# "SWIFT" string to name array

Tags: swift

String to name array?

```
var listArr = ["arr1","arr2","arr3","arr4"]
var arr1 = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
var arr2 = ["aaw","aww","awwww"]


let test1 = listArr[0]  // get "arr1" - string
test1[2]        // ??? need "cc"
```

// ( ok, other way

vet test2 = listArr[0] + "2"

test2[0] // ??? need "aaw"

Comment: What are you asking how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a dictionary.

```
var listArr = ["arr1","arr2","arr3","arr4"]
arrays = {"arr1": ["aa", "bb"], "arr2": ["aaa", "bbb"]}

let test1 = arrays[listArr[0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to join your array into one and then wanted to access the element then you can use `flatMap` like this.

```
var arr1 = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]
var arr2 = ["aaa","aaa","aaa"]
var arr3 = ["ddd","ddd","ddd"]
var arr4 = ["ttt","ttt","ttt","ttt"]
let listArr = [arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4].flatMap{$0}//Output will be ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "ddd", "ddd", "ddd", "ttt", "ttt", "ttt", "ttt"]
for str in listArr {
  print(str)
}
```